# Getting injector error even if the factory is returning the object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Its been like 6-7 months now with Angular and I have acquired not much but a relevant knowledge. But from past one day I am stuck on this error as shown below:

> Error: [$injector:undef]
>
> http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.5/$injector/undef?p0=DataService
>
> Stack trace: K/<@http://localhost:64965/Scripts/angular.min.js:7:76

Below is my service code:

```
(function () {
    var DataService = function ($http) {
        var allItems = function () {
            return $http.get("./data/myData.json").then(function (serviceResp) {
                return serviceResp.data;
            });
        };
    };

    app.factory("DataService", ["$http", DataService]); 
}());
```

Below is my controller code:

```
(function () {
    var ItemController = function ($scope, DataService) {
        var allItems = function (data) {
            $scope.collection = data;
        };
    };
    app.controller("ItemController", ["$scope", "DataService", ItemController])
}());
```

The factory is returning the object but still I am getting the above error. I tried cleaning the cache several times and restarted the app many times.

Comment: factory must return a value/obj. You are not returning anything

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but could you please point where should I put the return statement.
Thanks again,

Comment: I am adding answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote your service is wrong.

It should be written in the following way:

```
var app = angular.module('ServiceExample',[]);
 var serviceExampleController =
              app.controller('ServiceExampleController', ServiceExampleController);
 var serviceExample = app.service('NameOfTheService', NameOfTheService);

 ServiceExampleController.$inject = ['NameOfTheService'] //protects from minification of js files

function ServiceExampleController(NameOfTheService){
     serviceExampleController = this;
     serviceExampleController.data = NameOfTheService.getSomeData();
 }

function NameOfTheService(){
     nameOfTheService = this;
     nameOfTheService.data = "Some Data";
     nameOfTheService.getSomeData = function(){
           return nameOfTheService.data;
     }     
}
```

Then in the HTML you can use it like:

```
<div ng-controller = "ServiceExampleController as serviceExample">
    {{serviceExample.data}}
</div>
```

If you are looking to use `factory` read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41055194/1475228).

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer, but I beg to differ. Actually I tried writing the factory in the same way as mentioned in the question and it worked. But the only difference is there I used ASP.NET API and here I am using simple json file.

Answer (score 0):

Factory must return a value/obj. You are not returning anything. I have not tested, but it should work.

```
(function () {
     var DataService = function ($http) {
         var allItems = function () {
             return $http.get("./data/myData.json").then(function (serviceResp)       {
                 return serviceResp.data;
             });
         };
       return allItems ;

     };


    app.factory("DataService", ["$http", DataService]); 
}());
```